Does a property management company signing a contract with an Internet Service Provider break monopoly laws?
A renter rents from a property management company. To get internet, the renter must buy service from Internet Service Provider (ISP) called 'A'. However, A raises prices after the promotional discount just like all ISPs do, and the renter can no longer afford the price. But the building/apartment the renter is in only allows ISP A to provide internet. The renter cannot get the cheaper ISP B to provide internet.
Of course the renter has some other options like moving to a different place or relying on mobile data, but those are not ideal.
Would this situation break monopoly laws? Can the renter somehow have ISP B install internet?

Don't know if it makes a difference, but did the hypothetical renter know about the "only ISP A" rule when they signed the lease?

Unless the tenant has agreed to that restriction in the lease.

This is a bit thin on facts to know. For example, is ISP A a regulated utility? Has it been granted a monopoly by the local government? Is there an ISP B out there who could provide the service? Would ISP B require physical improvements to the property? What is the market share of the landlord/property manager in the rental market?
